# How to upload a HEX file to Arduino in Java?

Tags: java, erlang, arduino, protocols

I'd like to upload a ready HEX file to an Arduino board. How can I do that in Java code?

Should I implement the STK500 protocol in Java? Are there any working solutions or examples in Java?

PS. I've found an [STK500 implementation](https://github.com/msantos/stk500) in [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29), but I don't know it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a hex file. There are only files. What's in them is irrelevant to the upload process. There's not enough information here to answer the question. How do you interface to the board?

Comment: hex file is compiled sketch file which is produced by Arduino IDE ( by compiler to be exact) and ready for upload. Arduinos are usually interfaced via serial

Comment: @user1103561: The appropriate term is "binary file"; hex (short for hexadecimal) is just a base to represent values in.

Comment: sorry for that, now i know it

Comment: @EJP: OP was referring to the Intel Hex file format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it pretty easily using Stk500 protocol (Uno, old arduinos only). The only thing you should pay attention is DTR/RTS.

Answer (score 1):

Wheel exists.  Use wheel.
Upload from Java by using the excellent AVRdude.

```
/*
A command line looks like this in a stock Arduino IDE:

D:\arduino-dev\arduino-1.0.3\hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude   
-CD:\arduino-dev\arduino-1.0.3\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf 
-v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino 
-P\\.\COM8 -b115200 -D -V 
-Uflash:w:e:\Temp\build100458372319682483.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex:i

Just write the binary to the .HEX file and let the dude upload it:
*/

String hexfile = "e:\somefolder\Blink.cpp.hex";
String exefile = "D:\arduino-dev\arduino-1.0.3\hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude";
String conffile = "D:\arduino-dev\arduino-1.0.3\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf";
String opts = " -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P\\.\COM8 -b115200 -D -V ";
String cmd = exefile +" -C"+ conffile + opts +" -Uflash:w:" + hexfile +":i";

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
int retcode = waitFor(proc);
```

Comment: how can it be used in android app? it's undesired to use native code as it depends on cpu arch and i have to compile, test and maintain it for each cpu arch. that's why i asked for java

Comment: You said nothing about uploading from an Android app.  On Android, you will not get a serial port without implementing some form of replacement for the FTDI driver.

Comment: The question is about uploading using java since Android uses java and the problem is not in the Serial but in way of interacting with bootloader.